# get user page email of facebook in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got facebook page details using pass page id and page access token to following code.

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'?access_token='.$page_access_token
```

I got all the page's details except email address.
how can I get the email address?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Facebook Page email.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: when we create a facebook page from create a page section we can add a email address.I want to know how can I get that email address in php?

Comment: If there is no API available, you cannot fetch it. I think it is due to privacy issue (to prevent spam emails).